# tshark - how to avoid to select null or empty http.referer fileds

Tags: tshark

On Tshark v. 3.0.5., I am trying to run these commands in order to select URLs typed directly from the user. So I need to exclude http.referer filed that are empty (on null).

```
tshark -Y "http.request == 1 and **!http.referer**" -T fields -e frame.time -e http.referer -e http.host -r traffic.pcap > no_referer.txt
bash: !http.referer: event not found

tshark -Y "http.request == 1 and **http.referer == ""**" -T fields -e frame.time -e http.referer -e http.host -r traffic.pcap > no_referer.txt
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
tshark: Unexpected end of filter string.
```

Do you have any idea about how can I select this data on tshark?

Answer (score 2):

Bash will expand `**` in your display filter to something you probably don't want because you are [using double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash). You can use single quotes to ensure that bash doesn't change the contents of the display filter.

Per [wireshark http docs](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/h/http.html), `http.referer` is a string, so checking against empty values is checking against `""`. So use `http.referer and !http.referer == ""` to get packets that have this field, but also where the field is not empty.

```bash
tshark -Y 'http.request == 1 and http.referer and !http.referer == ""' ...
```

**Note**: `field != value` and `!field == value` are different, and the latter is preferred. dftest [can be used](https://tshark.dev/analyze/packet_hunting/dftest/#example--behavior) to demonstrate why this is.